# Using multiple loaders in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, es6-module-loader, swc

Loaders in Node can be used to hook into the module loading process, intercepting `import` or `require` calls. This works fine, but sometimes you might want to use multiple loaders. For instance, you are using some loader based on [ESBuild](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/esm-loader), ts-node or [SWC](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/2528#issuecomment-1665509100) to load your "normal" test code, but then you figure out you also want to use [Quibble](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quibble) to intercept *some* calls for certain ESM modules.

Currently, using multiple loaders is not directly supported, although [work is underway](https://github.com/nodejs/loaders#purpose), so I am wondering how to achieve this today using workarounds. I guess one would somehow write a wrapper to delegate between different loaders, alternatively feed the output of one into another?

I see [the API for loaders](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#transpiler-loader) seem manageable, but any practical hints on achieving this is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I was wrong in saying you could not use multiple loaders today. It is just that the API (as it always has been) is marked experimental and unstable. You can regard it [as a chain of handlers feeding into each other](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#loaders), just as with `require`:

```
node \
  --experimental-loader unpkg \
  --experimental-loader http-to-https \
  --experimental-loader cache-buster
```

This answer is incomplete, so will add to it (or someone else can edit it) when I know more.

Comment: Not knowing when I will get to it, others are free to edit and expand.